# Law of large numbers without any assumption

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I read the textbook Probability: Theory and Examples. 5th Edition by Durrett. Here is theorem 2.2.6 from the textbook.

Let $\mu_n=E(S_n)$, $\sigma_n^2=var(S_n)$. If $\sigma_n^2/b_n^2 \to 0$ then

$\frac{S_n-\mu_n}{b_n} \to 0$ in probability.

The textbook mentioned that $S_n$ can be any sequence of random variables. There is no independent and identical distributed assumptions. By this theorem, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, $b_n=n$, I would like to claim the statement below.

$X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are random variables, $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, $\sigma_n^2=var(S_n)$. If $\sigma_n^2/n^2 \to 0$ then

$\frac{S_n}{n} \to \frac{E(S_n)}{n}$ in probability.

I am just wondering if my statement is correct?

Comment: Yes, just use Chebyshev inequality, i.e: $\mathbb P( |\frac{S_n}{n} - \frac{\mathbb E[S_n]}{n} | > \varepsilon) \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \frac{\sigma_n^2}{n^2} \to 0$

Comment: You cannot write $a_n \to c_n$. You should change it to $a_n-c_n \to 0$.